# Java stack trace regex

Tags: java, regex, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I need to match Java stack trace
if it is a stack trace like this one

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A book has a null property
        at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookIds(Author.java:38)
        at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myproject.Book.getId(Book.java:22)
        at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookIds(Author.java:36)
```

I can match it with `^[[:space:]]+(at|\.{3})\b|^Caused by:`
The problem is i need to match the entire stack trace and the traces i get look like this:

```
2019-06-14 15:07:08,142 ThreadPoolAsyncTaskExecutor::Thread 65 ERROR bamboo_user 906x78989x1 vg7ahz 192.168.181.28 /rest/plugins/1.0/bg.nemetschek.jsd.advance-customer-reports-key [o.e.g.b.e.i.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor] Unable to create application context for [bg.nemetschek.jsd.advance-customer-reports], unsatisfied dependencies: none
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [bundle://293.0:0/META-INF/spring/atlassian-plugins-component-imports.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The bundle is uninstalled.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:170)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$800(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$3.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.startRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.stageOne(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.refresh(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:177)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.activator.LifecycleManager$1.run(LifecycleManager.java:207)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The bundle is uninstalled.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.getBundleResources(Felix.java:1624)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.getResources(BundleImpl.java:661)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.getResources(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:185)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.getHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.support.NamespacePlugins$Plugin.resolve(NamespacePlugins.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.support.NamespacePlugins$5.operate(NamespacePlugins.java:209)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.support.NamespacePlugins$5.operate(NamespacePlugins.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.support.LazyBundleRegistry.apply(LazyBundleRegistry.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.support.NamespacePlugins.doResolve(NamespacePlugins.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.support.NamespacePlugins.resolve(NamespacePlugins.java:169)
        ... 2 filtered
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.TrackingUtil$OsgiServiceHandler.invoke(TrackingUtil.java:106)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy605.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.DelegatedNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DelegatedNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:55)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1406)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:168)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        ... 20 more
```

The actual problem is that `... 20 more` or `... 2 filtered` is not getting matched and i cant match the entire trace so i can take it as one string.

Comment: Overall, this is just an bad idea. If you need to be informed about probable exceptions, add that functionality in your code instead of scanning log files

Comment: i am not scanning the files, i need the log for ELK stack. It needs to be visible in Kibana so devs can see the stack traces there because the environment is not accessible from their workstations. Also some of the exceptions are from Jira/Confluence, i need them also, and i cant touch the code there

Comment: Still sounds like you should pass any exception on when it pops up in the code instead of trying to match log files

Comment: I cant do this with proprietary Atlassian products....most of stack traces are indeed coming from Jira and/or third party plugin installed on Jira. I have no power there.

Comment: If you can any method from within your code, then its your job to handle that exception. Any 3rd party library throws their exceptions instead of handling them on their own.

Comment: It is not my code. This is my task. I don't need to "handle" them i need to show them to devs so they know what to do.

Comment: So you are scanning log files?

Comment: I am using Filebeat to send those files to Elasticsearch. Regex is for filebeat. My point is i am not PARSING them. I just need to figure out how to get the entire stacktrace when it is present. Not the trace in two halves.

Comment: You could match all lines which don't start with date and time (2019-06-14 15:07:08,142). Unless you have logging which spans multiple lines and doesn't prepend the date/time in every line, this will match every line within the exception

Comment: Unfortunately this is only a small part of the log. Other lines are being matched by single line patterns. This, however, is not the only multiline message that i will get. The only problem for now is this type of traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option might be to match from a string starting with a date. Then repeat all lines that do not start with a date or have `at`. Then make sure to match at least 1 line with `at` and then match all lines untill the next date:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*(?:\n(?!(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\h+at)).*)*\n\h+at\h+.*(?:\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*` Match a date like pattern followed by 0+ times any char except new line
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\n(?!(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\h+at)).*` match a newline, then assert what is on the right is not a datelike pattern or 1+ horizontal whitespace chars followed by `at`. If that is the case, match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\n\h+at\h+.*` Match a line starting with `at` surrounded by 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?:\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*)*` Match all lines not starting with a datelike pattern

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LrqM48/2)

Note in Java to double escape the backslash:

```
String regex = "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}.*(?:\\n(?!(?:\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}|\\h+at)).*)*\\n\\h+at\\h+.*(?:\\n(?!\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).*)*";
```

Comment: Thanks man! I will test this on the server and will let you know how it goes :)

Comment: @fixxxera, is it possible for the log file to contain log entries other than exception?

Comment: yes, it will for sure. Every entry will start with timestamp like this `2019-06-14 14:25:26,567`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just tested and it's working as needed.

Comment: You can use `multiline.match` in filebeat for harvesrting mulitline messages like stack traces. Refer this link for details - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html

Comment: this is what i did @Mishi

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `^(?:Caused by:|\s+(?:at|\.{3})).*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/shnaIy/1)

Comment: Thank you! This however does not match the first two lines. It does match all text after `The bundle is uninstalled.` I need all lines as one message.

Comment: I assumed you were only interested in the stacktrace (starting with at). Is it guaranteed that the exception details always start with yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: It is guaranteed. The message will always look like this.

Comment: I've tested this `^[[:space:]]+(at|\.{3})\b|^(?:Caused by:|\s+(?:at|\.{3})).*$` and it works without the two lines at the start (timestamp lines and beginning of the exception )